# How to debug a preprocessor macro

Tags: c, debugging, c-preprocessor

I recently came across [this project](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/metis/metis/overview). The code is largely written in C and the API consists of just a few C functions. Unfortunately the project seems to contain some bugs, in particular I keep getting "double free or corruption" errors. I am trying to use valgrind and gdb to find out what is wrong. The problem seems to be in the memory allocator. Unfortunately the first valgrind error occurs in some ~400 line long preprocessor macro defined in a header. Unfortunately gdb can't break on the generated code. The stack trace is not very useful either. Is there any technique which can be used to deal with these kind of errors?

Comment: If it were me? Convert the macro into an inline function. If the project really uses them that extensively (and that didn't scare me off from using the code), I might try preprocessing to a file, and then compiling and debugging that file.

Comment: 400+lines macro Oo ! Try to generate the c source after the preprocessor pass (gcc -E option) and set breakpoints in this file.

Comment: Well, they define a generic priority queue "the C way" :(

Comment: Ehm, did I read that right? A **400 line** preprocessor macro?? Strong recommendation: instantly forget about that thing!

Comment: As usual, you should try to produce the simplest possible code that exhibit the problem and either show it here or submit it on the support page for the project and you want external help. If you want to deal with it alone, also write a short example, and if you really need to debug an external macro, let the compiler generate the intermediary step after macro pre-processing (-E option for gcc), remove the `#line`pragmas from the pre-processed  source and debug that pre-processed code.

Comment: What is exact source code you work on it. I download its directory and what to work on it.

Answer (score 3):

The online compiler Wandbox.org has a "CPP" mode that is very useful to experiment with the C preprocessor.

See an example here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/tFUsKMIXaQj8hhte

You can do the same thing offline, with `gcc -P` or `cl.exe /E`